# Getting the possible routes and the distance between two given points

Tags: php, math, formula

I have a very challenging assignment.

I need to create a PHP function that will list all the routes between two given points, order by the shortest distance.
Example what are the routes for point A and E. List all the routes ordered by their distance.

I tabulated it to this:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
A   0   5   9   10  29
B   5   0   9   11  13
C   9   9   0   1   9
D   10  11  1   0   10
E   29  13  9   10  0
```

Distance from A to B is 5, A to C is 9 and so on.

Please help. Thank you so much!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Graph_algorithms

Comment: @Michael I'm trying to follow this https://www.sitepoint.com/data-structures-4/, the finding the shortest-path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), as this topic is really old and well discussed on the internet, i won't try to reinvent the wheel and try to copy paste bunch of text. Possible php implementations can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75641/dijkstras-algorithm-in-php) or [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/data-structures-4/).

Comment: I didn't know there's an algorithm for this. I'm now looking at Dijkstra's algorithm. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Taiga glad i could help

Comment: @Taiga, You should upvote and accept this very good answer if it helped you.  It's spot on.